# Sharing scope variable between sibling directives

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, coffeescript, angularjs-scope

I'm working on a table that can be expanded/collapsed by clicking on the header bar.  To accomplish this, I have two directives that appear in the markup as siblings:  slideToggle and slideable.  I want to share a variable that contains open/closed state between the two directives.  I've created a parent directive, slideContainer, as an API because from what I understand sibling directives cannot share a controller instance on their own.  I want the state to be able to be set in the markup by adding an attribute to the slideContainer element.  The variable should be accessed, kept up to date, and mutable from all three directives, and two way binding should be accessible to the DOM as parts of the view will depend on the state. At first I thought I'd post here to get a sense of the "best" approach for accomplishing this but I've tried many approaches out and can't quite get it to work.  Here's where I'm at now:

`slideable.coffee:`

```
directives.directive "slideContainer", () ->
  link: (scope, element, attrs) ->
    scope.closed = "closed" in attrs
  controller: ($scope) ->
    this.closed = $scope.closed

directives.directive "slideToggle", () ->
  scope: {}
  require: "^slideContainer"
  link: (scope, element, attrs, slideContainerCtrl) ->
    scope.closed = slideContainerCtrl.closed

    target = null
    content = null

    element.bind "click", () ->
      target = document.querySelector(attrs.slideToggle) if (!target)
      content = target.querySelector(".slideable_content") if (!content)

      if slideContainerCtrl.closed
        target.style.maxHeight = content.clientHeight + "px"
      else
        target.style.maxHeight = "0px"

      slideContainerCtrl.closed = !slideContainerCtrl.closed

directives.directive "slideable", () ->
  scope: {}
  restrict: "C"
  require: "^slideContainer"
  compile: (element, attr) ->
    contents = element.html()
    element.html("<div class='slideable_content'>#{contents}</div>")

    (scope, element, attrs, slideContainerCtrl) ->
      transProp = attrs.transProp || "max-height"
      transTimeFunc = attrs.transTimeFun || "linear"
      transDur = attrs.transDur || "0.5s"
      maxHeight = if slideContainerCtrl.closed "0" else "1000px"

      element.css({
          "overflow": "hidden",
          "max-height": maxHeight,
          "transition": "#{transProp} #{transTimeFunc} #{transDur}",
          "width": "100%"
      })
```

`table.html:`

```
<div slideContainer closed>
  <!-- initial state determined by presence of closed attr above -->
  <div slideToggle>
    <img ng-if="closed" src="closed.jpg">
    <img ng-if="!closed" src="open.jpg">
    <!-- TABLE TITLE -->
  </div>
  <table class="=open-ended-in-process-table slideable">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <!-- COLUMN TITLES -->
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr ng-repeat="thing in list">
        <!-- TABLE DATA -->
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: have you tried using service?

Comment: I don't think a service would work since it's a singleton and multiple tables need to use this setup independently.  I'd have to create a service for each table which doesn't seem like a good approach.

Comment: if I understand your question correctly. You want the three directives as a set and later you will have multiple sets of these three directives independently. If so, you can keep a variable in each directive. And use $broadcast, $emit, and $on to update the variable in each directive. May not be the best approach but should be able to solve your problem. Does it make sense?

Comment: or you can combine the three directive into just one.